# Displaying the last viewed data

Tags: php

When I access a page for example viewing a user information. Here's the scenario. The user views the information for person A, and then views the information for person B but what is displayed on the browser is the information for person A and it will only go away once you refresh the browser. What do you think is the problem here?

Here's a sample code:

```
<?php foreach($select as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="schedule_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>"/>
                <td><input type="text" id="description_<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>" name="description[]" value="<?php echo $row->quarter; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="range_from_<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>" name="range_from[]" value="<?php echo $row->new_range_from; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="range_to_<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>" name="range_to[]" value="<?php echo $row->new_range_to; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="sched_from_<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>" name="sched_from[]" value="<?php echo $row->sched_from; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="sched_to_<?php echo $row->schedule_id; ?>" name="sched_to[]" value="<?php echo $row->sched_to; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

It's just a usual code I didn't really do anything. But I'm suspecting that the configuration is the problem so if you would be so kind to look at my php.ini file:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27328449/php.ini

I was using Wampserver during the development but on production I installed php, apache and mysql separately. So I think this has something to do with the configuration.

Thank you for all the comments.

Comment: Absolutely no idea .... some code would probably help though

Comment: And there is no need to start the question title with *PHP* or the description with *I have a problem in PHP* when you tagged it `PHP`

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you if you don't post some of the php code that is relevant for the displaying the information of the users you have.

Comment: I didn't post any code because I think this is a configuration issue. Please look at my php.ini file I have already updated the file and provided some sample code. I also have output buffering enabled in my config file if that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is probably caching the html of your page. Fix:

Add these two lines at the top of your page in php:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

via http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Were the headers correctly sent? Can you check in your browser's http console? Could you try disabling your browser's cache?

Comment: I don't know how where the http console is. Is this the one: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27328449/Capture.PNG

Comment: looks good. Is the response part bad too? If so, go to net>down arrow> disable browser cache & try again